# Django DynamicSites database error

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get the Django DynamicSites (multi-site) application (see https://bitbucket.org/uysrc/django-dynamicsites/src and http://blog.uysrc.com/2011/03/23/serving-multiple-sites-with-django/) up and running on Django 1.3.1, but I keep getting "Database Error: No such column django_site.folder_name."

I've set up a site in the admin panel, run syncdb and followed every single instruction, but I still can't figure out why I'm getting this error on only this application (have tried resetting it and doing a "fresh" install of it, too, but with no luck).  I've followed the instructions on the site (above) verbatim.  Anyone have suggestions or having similar issues?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there is a bug in the package that doesn't add the **folder_name** and **subdomains** columns to the Sites table in the Django database.  Using a database browser, I've added them manually (using the ALTER TABLE command) and DynamicSites appears to work now.